# Not to apply Leading and Trailing Constraints when UICollectionViewCell doesn't resize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I am working on horizontal layout where the cell's dynamically update when the text size grows. Currently I have a UICollectionViewCell whose estimate size is 100 and have leading and trailing margins set as 12.

However, its adding such constraint even when the text doesn't grows which leads to increase the original size of the cell as well.

I have tried lowering the priority of the leading and trailing constraints but it still grows 12 points each side even when text is not growing. Is there any way to not let the constraint get applied if the size of the text doesn't grows or shrinks  lower than of the estimate size?

Comment: Have you tried setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`?

Comment: Can you share one example to simulate here ?